# Importing CSV data into SQL gives Expecting '.', ID or QUOTED_ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am following examples straight out of other questions here on Stack and am getting the following error (which I don't understand):

"Incorrect syntax near @UserNames. Expecting '.', ID or QUOTED_ID"

**THE SQL LOOKS LIKE:**

```
DECLARE @CsvFilePath NVARCHAR(1000) = 'C:\Temp\UserNames.csv';
DECLARE @UserNames TABLE ( UserName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

BULK INSERT @UserNames FROM @CsvFilePath WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
GO
```

Comment: I don't think you can bulk insert table variables. Also, I don't think you can use a parameter for the file name, you would need to generate dynamic SQL to to that part.

Comment: You know that nvarchar is 2 bytes for every character which means that the longest a line can be is 50 chars.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot BULK INSERT into a table variable. Change this line

```
DECLARE @UserNames TABLE ( UserName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```

and use a table

```
CREATE TABLE tblUserNames ( UserName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```

or temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #tblUserNames ( UserName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```